# error while executing JateToolkit

Tags: java

I am using the jate toolkit, compilation works well, when i run the program, it did not find the root nlp_ressources folder while reading jate.proprieties, despite the path exist. you find below the file jate.proprieties:

```
jate.system.nlp=jate.system.nlp=C:/Users/faffou/workspace/nlp_resources
jate.system.term.maxwords=5 
jate.system.term.ignore_digits=true
jate.system.term.frequency.counter.multithread=5
```

The error message is below. Please who can help me!!!

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\faffou\workspace\Test\nlp_resources\stoplist.txt (Le chemin d’accès spécifié est introuvable)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at uk.ac.shef.dcs.oak.jate.util.control.StopList.loadStopList(StopList.java:44)
at uk.ac.shef.dcs.oak.jate.util.control.StopList.<init>(StopList.java:30)
at uk.ac.shef.dcs.oak.jate.test.TestTfIdf.main(TestTfIdf.java:62)
```

Comment: If you're sure the file exists at that path, check that the permissions on it are correct. Also check that you have specified it using the correct case. I'm not familiar with Windows file permissions or case-sensitivity but that's what I'd check for on a linux system.

Comment: Thinks, I am verifying permissionsz and case. everythink is ok.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have `stoplist.txt` file in this folder. Jate tries to load `stoplist.txt` which has configuration about the words which shouldn't be processed make sure it exists if not try with creating empty one! I don't remember structure of this file unfortunately.

Comment: the file exist in the foolder, i don't understand why he doesn't see it.

Answer (score 0):

Thinks for your responses.
I solved the problem, in fact I changed the path of my file and I changed the shape of the url from:

```
C:/Users/faffou/workspace/Test/nlp_resources
```

to

```
C://nlp_resources
```